# biblatex and biber incompatible? [Texlive+Texstudio]

Tags: biblatex

So I'm writing a report and changed my OS a while back and had to reinstall latex. I used the texlive installer for linux. I am user biber for my bibliography and this used to work, I now however get this error;

```
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.0, expected version 3.5.
This means that your biber (2.12) and biblatex () versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
```

I cannot figure out how to down/upgrade the package correctly. Texlive is completely up to date (biblatex 3.12) + (biber 2.12). There's no obvious downgrading option with `tlmgr`, how do I fix this?

Edit1;

In the compatibility matrix it tells me 2.12 and 3.12 should work together... What's the issue here?

Edit2;

Sorry I am a total derp, I was removing the wrong .aux/.bcf etc files from another project which is almost identical. That's what I get for not having my morning coffee I suppose...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you update recently? If so, you might have a previous `.bcf` file which may be incompatible. If that's the case, deleting aux files and compiling anew may help.

Comment: @gusbrs where do I find these .bcf files? Also I am having trouble to reinstall Tex live since I used the binary (I cant use apt-get remove either because I'm on manjaro). Sorry I'm a total tex noob. 


Note; I may or may not have installed tex in both manjaro's package manager and seperately with the binary, so executables are probably a mess. I already tried removing some but no dice.

Comment: Delete all temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`) and recompile from scratch. If the problem still persists double check that you only have one TeX distribution installed on your machine and not several different TeXs that interfere with each other. Check if the paths returned by `which biber` and `which pdflatex` look similar.

Comment: It should be alongside your .tex file, in the same directory.

Comment: @Berghopper Does your last edit mean the problem is solved?

Comment: @gusbrs yep, my confusion was in the filetype as well. I thought you meant some installation files of TexLive rather than simple compilation files found in the projects directories.